# How can I hide faces on SCNGeometry(e.g. SCNBOX) to show only edges?

Tags: 3d, ios8, scenekit

I don't need textures and just want a hollow box with edges.
How can I make the box like this with SCNGeometry?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take a look at `SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeLine`.
Basically you would need to change the `primitiveType` of each of its geometry elements.